# Json to Javascript from file

Tags: javascript, json

задание простое: достать обьекты из json файла и запихнуть в массив в виде обьектов. Как это сделать, как это будет работать(можно ссылку на статью, буду величайше благодарен) и почему данный код, который я нашел на просторах сети не работает?

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
        callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
}

//usage:
readTextFile("clients.json", function(text){
var data = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(data);
});
```

Огромное спасибо

Comment: `не работает` == `работает не так, как вы ожидали`? Если да, то что делает этот код и что вы ожидали?

Comment: код плюется ошибками, 
jsonArray.js:10 Failed to load file:///Users/gregorykisenko/Documents/projects/inCode%20test%20project/clients.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
мне нужен массив с данными из json, или итератор для этих данных в виде обьектов

Comment: Так вы файл с диска пытаетесь считать, это так не работает. Не пробовали почитать текст ошибки, перевести его, или может быть даже в гугле поискать?)

Comment: Да, я понял, что в браузере есть ограничение на чтение инфы с диска, но мне все еще непонятно, как обычно решают данную проблему?

Comment: Просто так из браузера доступа к диску вы не получите. Кроссбраузерный запрос тоже просто так не сделаете :) Либо делать это на бэкенде, либо получать файл от пользователя, либо хранить в статике (опять же на бэкенде), чтобы по какому-то релативному пути получать доступ к файлам.